# MVC and ADFS Development Not Impossible Easily?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, adfs2.0, adfs

Using VS2010 and MVC3 and the latest Razor engine bits.

I have a request to integrate ADFS to allow the app to support single-sign-on for an existing Windows domain.

This does not look like a trivial operation, and it also appears that I would have to develop on Windows 2008 and not Windows 7 in order to develop/test ADFS.

Looking at urls like

[ADFS v2.0 Error : MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '1' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640030/adfs-v2-0-error-msis7042-the-same-client-browser-session-has-made-6-requests)

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2010/04/03/wif-and-mvc-how-it-works.aspx

are making me think this is going to be a *lot* of work.

Any comments on how to make MVC3 and AFDS work quickly and well?

Thanks.